# convert from double to int in anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to convert a double value to int and use it in the number of agents per arrival. I have a distribution but want it to round to the nearest integer. I looked up the anylogic math functions but the only one that makes sense is rint but that still returns a double.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this:

```
(int) rint(yourVariable)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use `(int)floor(myDouble))` and `(int)ceil(myDouble))` .

With these, you can decide if you want to round up or down (if the default rounding rules aren't to your liking)